# ReactJS cant update input value

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have some data in the `redux` store which is now mapped to props.

This is my fields:

```
<input value={this.props.bill.flat_rent} name="flat_rent" type="number"></input>
```

This fields automatically filled with the data from props, later i try ti edit this fields but it doesnt allow to edit the value.

Can anyone help how can edit the value?

In my case, I cant use `state` data. I have data in props,  cant anyone help how to do it?

Comment: Either use an [uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) and set defaultValue instead of value or use a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and add onChange handler that you got from the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have props data before mounting child component, you can go with this

```
this.state = {
  flatRent: props.bill.flat_rent,
}
```

if you does not have props data while mounting child, then you cant use `setState`
and you need to `dispatch` an action, so that it will update your `props` value in the `redux-store`

```
<input value={this.props.bill.flat_rent} name="flat_rent" type="number"onChange={(e) => this.props.updateBill({flat_rent: e.target.value})}></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch action onChange of input field and then configure the action in reducer so that you can get updated value in the input field

```
<input value={this.props.bill.flat_rent} name="flat_rent" type="number"onChange={e=>dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_FLAT_RENT", payload: e.target.value})></input>
```